# Graph not displaying Java-Script

Tags: javascript, graph, charts

```
<script>
// Data Values for the chart.

var newArray = new Array();
var newArray = <?php echo json_encode($values); ?>;

// Bar Chart.
if($("#chart-3").length > 0)
{

    var data = [];          
    for( var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = { data: newArray[i]}; // this causing problem.
        console.log(data[i]);
    }

    $.plot($("#chart-3"), data, 
    {
        series:
        {
            pie: { show: true }
        },
        legend: { show: false }
    });
}
</script>
```

If i put `4` in place of `newArray[i]` then graph is displaying values. I used the console.log() to check what values i am getting in newArray and what i am getting is:

**console.log() output:**

```
Object {data: "4"}
Object {data: "2"}
```

Comment: not seeing anything wrong with your code above.  can you create a jsfiddle, or link to a site, that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: ^ is this "4" means 4 ? or it will get in the data part in "4" form?

Comment: good point @user3400389.  you might parse that to a number type...see answer below

Comment: is there a function like newArray[i].toValue()? i think this the issue i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the numeric value is indeed numeric and not a string, you could do this:

```
data[i] = { data: parseInt(newArray[i])};
```

or use `parseFloat` if that is more appropriate.

Comment: Perfect. that was the problem. "4" was going into the data and not 4. Thanks +1.